# how to show alert after calling the webservice

Tags: android, web-services, android-alertdialog

In my activity I am calling webservices. So after the webservice returns the result, I have to show an alert. Since alert is UI part, I think inside onPostExecute() I have to write the alert code. But when I do like that error is coming.

Error shown:

```
12-02 09:59:08.508: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting 
due to uncaught exception
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451): 
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token 
android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@4378eb50 is not valid; is your 
activity running?
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at 
android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:456)
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at 
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at 
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at 
android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:409)
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at
android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:238)
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at 
android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at    com.myapp.android.activities.Register$PostCodeTask.onPostExecute(Register.java:291)
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at     com.myapp.android.activities.Register$PostCodeTask.onPostExecute(Register.java:1)
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at
android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:416) 
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at 
android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at 
android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:428)
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
12-02 09:59:08.528: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(451):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 
Method)
```

Can anyone please help to solve my issue. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Mathew Can you please show us pseudo code.

Comment: can you post the alert message code segment that you used. And try generating the alert inside a UI thread.

Comment: (please don't abuse the "flag => requires moderator attention"; that is for admin purposes, for example deleting inappropriate content)

Comment: ok...sorry misunderstood flag...

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute your alert code in UI thread. There are few ways of doing it for example

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Hello there", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: toast will work. But alert is not coming. Still the same error.

Comment: Hope you are not missing alert.show() call. Happened to me more than once